# Ordering Primers: When to choose wet vs dry delivery format?

Tags: dna, primer, lab-reagents

Whenever ordering primers, I'm always asked to specify which delivery matrix I prefer to have the oligos delivered in: wet (in water or some kind of TE buffer) vs. dry.

My understanding is that when stored dry, the primers can last up to 24 months in the freezer. However, for the primers to be useable, one needs to rehydrate them into the appropriate concentration.

So I'm wondering, what are the pros/cons of having primers shipped wet vs dry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pros of wet:

1. No need to rehydrate to use.
2. For e.g. 96-well plates, this can be a big deal as it's a pain to do this for large numbers of samples.
3. More accurate concentrations (oligo manufactureres are better at rehydrating oligos with e.g. accurate volumes than most people).

Pros of dry:

1. last longer (until rehydrated)
2. cheaper

Comment: This is great summary of the pros/cons. Thanks!